# Updating TextBox in a windows form from a public method outside the form

Tags: winforms, textbox, c++-cli

I have a windows form (`Form1.h`) with a `Button` and a `TextBox`. The `TextBox` is empty when the form is initialized. On button click, a method outside the form is called and it should update the `TextBox`. How would I make an update of the `TextBox` from a non-form class? Below is my sample code:

```
// Form1.h
private: System::Void findResultButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    FirstResults* firstResults = new FirstResults();
    firstResults->findResult();
}

// FirstResults.cpp
void FirstResults::findResult() { 
    // do some calculations here and find result.
    // write the result value to a .txt file.
    // Update TextBox in Form1.h with result value.
}
```

Comment: Not an expert in C++, but could you simply pass the reference to the textcontrol to your function and then update the text there?

Comment: Return a `List<String^>^` from that function.  Or pass it a delegate so it can make a callback.  Something like that.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. I have tried it with the delegates and now I am looking for ways to declare managed delegates in unmanged class.

Comment: Type "marshal::getfunctionpointerfordelegate" in the search box.  First hit looks good.

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah, I am already reading through. Seems like I am bumping into you everytime I look for the exact help. Anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create a static instance of the form.
Then in any .cpp file you want to access the TextBox1 or TextArea you just

```
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    static Form1^ myForm1;

    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myForm1 = this;
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }
}
```

Then in .cpp `#include "form1.h"`
and

```
Form1^ myform1 = gcnew Form1();
Form1::myForm1->textBox1->Text = L" FROM the main.cpp ";
```

Or if you need

```
System::Windows::Forms::myform1->textBox1->Text = L" FROM the main.cpp ";
```